# Adding user defined using clauses on adding a new class in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have added several projects to a VS 2010 solution. In Client Project whenever I add a new class I need to add several using clauses, However It shows some system defined using clauses.

How can I configure VS 2010 to have user defined using clauses for adding a new class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this step:

1. Open this directory:

   for 64 bit: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033`

   for 32 bit: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033`
2. Open `Class.zip`, there is `Class.cs`, modify that file as you want, then save.
3. Run `devenv.exe /installvstemplates` to launch the visual studio with new templates.